# Is there any way that I can make shortcuts from my Windows Programs in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, wine, shortcuts

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu as Dual Boot, is there any way that I can make a shortcut from one of my existing Windows programs, in my "App Draw" so that I may open it in Wine?

I'm using Gnome-shell.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Computer. Click on the drive that has Windows on it.

Click on Program Files.

Search for the specified app. The app should come up and you can put it onto the desktop by click and drag, and copy and paste.

After dragging it to the desktop, drag it to the Unity Launcher.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps :) but is there then a way that I can add it to my launcher in Unity?

Comment: See edit. :-) @JonathanRead